# Precise timing of limit order execution in pine script v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a stop order that enters will open a position in the middle of a bar if the price goes above a certain amount.

When it fires, in the backtest trade results, the time is marked as the start of the bar time. Is there any way for me to see the actual execution time (not just with replay?). It would be helpful for debugging.

I tried putting the time in the alert comments, but that only prints the current time.

```
enterLongComment = "Enter long comment" + str.tostring(hour(timenow), "00:") + str.tostring(minute(timenow), "00:") + str.tostring(second(timenow), "00")
exitLongComment = "Exit long comment"+ str.tostring(hour(timenow), "00:") + str.tostring(minute(timenow), "00:") + str.tostring(second(timenow), "00")
```

Answer (score 0):

timenow is for the current time.
Check out this: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_time

Just like this:

```html
    enterLongComment = "Enter long comment" + str.tostring(hour(time(1S)), "00:")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but it doesn't seem to work. Now I get a time exactly one bar before the bar starts in which the stop order is set (even though stop order opens in the middle of the next bar).

Comment: Did you tried with "str.tostring(hour(time(1S))" instead of timeframe.period?

Comment: Tried '1S' but it still gives the bar start times, not in between when the stop was reached.